# call a partial view if and only if method call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view in _Layout page

to bind values to that partial view I need to call specific method with some Ids, but this not default page loading method, and same _layout page use for this default view page

but when this debug this application its going to initial load and saying that

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

in Partial view page

this is how I call to PartialView in _Layout page

```
Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_UserPartialView.cshtml", new Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel())
```

this is my PartialView

```
@model Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel

    @foreach (var item in Model.User)
    {
    }
```

how to avoid situation like this, call that partial view if and only if specific method call

Comment: The error occurs because the `User` property of `UserViewModel` is `null`. You can overcome the error by include a default costructor that initializes it e.g. (`public UserViewModel() { Users = new List<User>(); }` Or you could use `@Html.Action(...)` to call a controller method that initializes it. But what do you mean _only if specific method call_? What is the condition for including it, and when should it be excluded?

Comment: to bind values to this partial view I have another controller method, its contains some parameters, the thing you suggested  in comment will try

Comment: @kez if you want the partial view to be rendered for only specific action methods then it is best to add the partial view to the views of those actions and pass the required model. And yes, it may be useful to learn about [@Html.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

call as below format:
@Html.RenderPartial("partial view path",Model)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code for validate your models:

```html
@model Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel

@if (Model.YourModel != null && Model.YourModel.Count() != 0)
 {
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_UserPartialView.cshtml", Model.YourModel)
 }
  else
{  <p>Model Error</p>   }
```